# Is it possible to call variables of a different object of the same class in Python?

Tags: python, function, object, parameters

I would like to create a function that takes in a different object from the same class, and then alter that object's parameters.  However, when I try to alter that object, instead of altering that object's variable it alter's the local object's.

**For example**:

```
 class MyClass():

     item = ''
     def __init__(self):
         self.item = ''
     def function(self, otherObject):
         otherObject.item = self.item
```

Heres my code:

```
class Taxonomy:
     categoryName = ''
     itemList = []

    def __init__(self,  itemList = []):
         self.categoryName = categoryName
         self.itemList = itemList  

    def addTaxonomy(self, tax):

        self.taxonomy_tree[''][self.categoryName][tax.categoryName]
        self.itemList.clear()
        self.itemList.append(self.categoryName)
        tax.itemList.clear()
```

For some reason the 'tax.itemList.clear()' clears both itemLists.

Comment: This should work. Just make sure you use `class MyClass(object):` (Python 2) or `class MyClass:` (Python 3).

Comment: You need to give some more context though: show example calls to MyClass().function(...).

Comment: The indentation got mixed up in the first edit.  I think I fixed it, but please check it over to make sure I did it correctly. . .

Comment: This code looks like it should work as you've described.  Can you give an example of it not working?

Comment: What don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: Ok I provided more context of my actual code.

Comment: How do you create the two objects? You might be getting bitten by the fact that your default value for `itemLIst` is mutable. For instance, if you have `a = Taxonomy(); b = Taxonomy()`, then both `a.itemList` and `b.itemList` refer to the same list object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `itemList` all point to the same instance of list. In python creating a default argument value with a mutable type is not a good idea. Take `def f(x=[]): pass`. This function share the same list for all call of f where no argument x is passed.

this code illustrate better what I am trying to say.

```
def f(x=[]):
    x.append(1)
    return x

f()
print f() # ouput: [1, 1]
```

Hopefully you can easily refactor using a default None value for your param.

```
def f(x=None):
    x = x or []
    x.append(1)
    return x

f()
print f() # ouput: [1]
```

A specific solution to your problem would be:

```
def __init__(self,  itemList = None):
     self.categoryName = categoryName
     self.itemList = itemList or []
```